# Multivariate optimization with non-trivial constraints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

In my current project, I must minimize the following objective function:

1/2 x **a**.T x (**A**.T x **A**) x **a** - **c**.T x log(**B** x **a**)

where **A** is a n-by-m matrix, **B** is a different n-by-m matrix, **c** is a n-by-1 vector, **a** is the desired m-by-1 vector of parameter values, and .T denotes the transpose. Everything except **a** can be assumed known.

Optimizing this would be pretty straightforward were it not for the second term with the logarithm. Because the logarithm exists, we must impose a constraint which ensures that **B** x **a** > 0.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Use one of the solvers supporting constraints (you will only find non-strict ineqs or strict eqs), choose an epsilon and post the constraint `B * a >= eps`.

Comment: You can formulate this constrained optimization as an unconstrained optimization of the corresponding Lagrangian, building on what @sascha suggested. Calc III's a bit beyond Stack Overflow's pay grade, though.